# How can I access the context of an option in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Is there any way to get the data context of an option tag generated with `{{#each}}`? Currently, I use two workarounds depending on the type of data I'm iterating over.

**Case 1 - Options Cursor**

```
<template name="select">
  <select>
    {{#each options}}
    <option value="{{_id}}">{{label}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

Options = new Meteor.Collection('options');
Template.select.events({
  'change select': function (e, t) {
    var option_doc = Options.findOne($(e.target).val());
  }
});
```

**Case 2 - Options Array**

```
<template name="select">
  <select>
    {{#each options}}
    <option>{{label}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

var options = [{label: "foo"}, {label: "bar"}];
Template.select.events({
  'change select': function (e, t) {
    var option_doc = options[e.target.selectedIndex];
  }
});
```

If this was using text input, `this` would be `option_doc` inside the event handler. However, since the change event triggers on select rather than option, `this` refers to the template's data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `UI.getElementData`.

From the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_getelementdata):

> ### UI.getElementData(el) *(Client)*
>
> Returns the data context that was used when rendering a DOM element from a Meteor template.
>
> #### Arguments
>
> `el` DOM Element
>   An element that was rendered by a Meteor template